# How to add button property into PropertyGrid?

Tags: properties, propertygrid

I have PropertyGrid named SettingsGrid

now fiil it:
`SettingsGrid.SelectedObject = _Config;`

Config include property

```
    private string _Export = "";
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Description("Export as")]
    [Category("Export settings")]
    public string Export
    {
        get { return _Export; }
        set { _Export = value; }
    }
```

as a result I have string "export" property into "export settings" category.

Now I need clickable property like button. How add this property?

Answer (score 0):

I used an object like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Doc
{
    public int Field{ get; set; }
    public int Value{ get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Field+ " <=> " + Value;
    }
}
```

and by pressing the button (...) opens the standart editor